# Behat scenario failing if run with other scenarios

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, behat

I have a rather odd one here today...

I have a Behat feature file that contains several scenarios.  Each of the scenarios will pass if run individually, however if I run the feature file in it's entirety, then one of the tests fails, with the error...

```
Notice: Undefined index: 00000000070885f90000000106598262 in /project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2058
```

... (shown below)

The scenarios load fixtures, and then navigates around the pages using the information in fixture entity, and then check page URLs are correct.

The weird thing is that the second test fails, only if the first one is run before it.  If it's not, then the context manages to successfully store the fixture entity as a property, and then use EntityManager::merge() and EntityManager::refresh() to reload the entity to it's current state.  When the first test is run before it, the context is still fetching and storing the fixture entity in the same way, but when it attempts to merge and refresh, for some reason the entity manager unit of work seems to have forgotten about it.

Before each scenario the d/b is cleared, and fixtures reloaded, using the code shown below.  I've also made sure I've called EntityManager::clear() to ensure that any remnants of the previous test are removed.

```
/**
 * Clears the d/b
 *
 * @throws ToolsException
 */
public function clearDb()
{
    foreach ($this->getEntityManagers() as $entityManager) {
        $metadata = $this->getMetadata($entityManager);
        if (!empty($metadata)) {
            $tool = new SchemaTool($entityManager);
            $tool->dropSchema($metadata);
            $tool->createSchema($metadata);
        }
    }
}
```

A bit more info from my investigation...

Having investigated further, it's not a problem if the first test just fetches the entity, stores it, but does not request a page (using Mink)

Files...

Behat test (with annotations)

```
@fix:Application\Stage9Submitted\SubmittedStage1 @fix:User\FundAdmin\FundAdmin1
Scenario: I can assign an application to a case worker
  Given I am logged in as "User\FundAdmin\FundAdmin1" fixture user
  And I am on the application admin "eligibility" page for "Application\Stage9Submitted\SubmittedStage1" fixture application
      ^== fetches amd saves as $currentEntity
  And I should see "Unassigned" in the ".application-summary .case-worker" element
  When I follow "Change case worker"
  And I select "fund.admin@example.com" from "project_application_admin_change_caseworker_caseWorker"
  And I press "Change case worker"
  Then I should be on the application admin "eligibility" page for that application
      ^== Retrieves $currentEntity and calls EntityManager::merge() and EntityManager::refresh()
      ^== This works

  And I should see "Fund Admin" in the ".application-summary .case-worker span[title='fund.admin@example.com']" element
  And I should see "Application assigned to Fund Admin"


@fix:Application\Stage9Submitted\SubmittedStage1 @fix:User\FundAdmin\FundAdmin1
Scenario: I can un-assign an application from a case worker
  Given I am logged in as "User\FundAdmin\FundAdmin1" fixture user
  And I am on the application admin "eligibility" page for "Application\Stage9Submitted\SubmittedStage1" fixture application
      ^== fetches amd saves as $currentEntity
  And I should see "Unassigned" in the ".application-summary .case-worker" element
  And I follow "Change case worker"
  And I select "fund.admin@example.com" from "project_application_admin_change_caseworker_caseWorker"
  And I press "Change case worker"
  And I should be on the application admin "eligibility" page for that application
      ^== Retrieves $currentEntity and calls EntityManager::merge() and EntityManager::refresh()
      ^== This fails (but only if the above test run at the same time!?!)
  ...
```

FixturesContext

```
<?php

namespace CubicMushroom\SymfonyFeatureContextBundle\Feature\Context;

use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareContext;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\ReferenceRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException;
use Project\DataFixtures\ORM\AbstractSingleFixture;
use Project\Exception\Feature\Context\FixtureContext\FixtureNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

/**
 * Loads fixtures based on scenario tags
 *
 * @package Project
 */
class FixturesContext implements KernelAwareContext
{
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Properties
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * @var KernelInterface
     */
    protected $kernel;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fixtureNamespaces;

    /**
     * @var Loader
     */
    protected $loader;

    /**
     * @var AbstractFixture[]
     */
    protected $loadedFixtures;

    /**
     * @var ORMExecutor
     */
    protected $executor;


    /**
     * NewFixturesContext constructor.
     *
     * @param array $fixtureNamespaces
     */
    public function __construct(array $fixtureNamespaces)
    {
        foreach ($fixtureNamespaces as $fixtureNamespace) {
            $this->addFixtureNamespace($fixtureNamespace);
        }
    }


    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // @BeforeScenario
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     *
     * @param BeforeScenarioScope $scope
     */
    public function loadFixturesFromTags(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
    {
        // We load this here, rather than in the constructor so it's re-initialised on each scenario
        $this->loader = new Loader();

        $tags = $scope->getScenario()->getTags();

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $this->loadFixturesForTag($this->loader, $tag);
        }

        $fixtures = $this->loader->getFixtures();

        if (empty($fixtures)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->clearDb();

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->clear();

        $purger         = new ORMPurger();
        $this->executor = new ORMExecutor($em, $purger);
        $this->executor->purge();
        $this->executor->execute($fixtures, true);

        $this->loadedFixtures = $fixtures;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $fixture
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getNamespacedFixtures($fixture)
    {
        $fixtures = [];

        foreach ($this->fixtureNamespaces as $fixtureNamespace) {

            $fixtureClass = "{$fixtureNamespace}\\{$fixture}";

            if (class_exists($fixtureClass)) {
                $fixtures[] = $fixtureClass;
            }
        }

        return $fixtures;
    }


    /**
     * Clears the d/b
     *
     * @throws ToolsException
     */
    public function clearDb()
    {
        foreach ($this->getEntityManagers() as $entityManager) {
            $metadata = $this->getMetadata($entityManager);
            if (!empty($metadata)) {
                $tool = new SchemaTool($entityManager);
                $tool->dropSchema($metadata);
                $tool->createSchema($metadata);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Loads the fixtures for a given tag
     *
     * @param Loader $loader
     * @param string $tag
     */
    protected function loadFixturesForTag(Loader $loader, $tag)
    {
        $parts  = explode(':', $tag);
        $prefix = array_shift($parts);

        // Only bother with tags staring 'fix:'
        if ('fix' !== $prefix) {
            return;
        }

        if (empty($parts)) {
            throw new \LogicException('No fixture provided');
        }

        $fixture = array_shift($parts);
        $args    = $parts;

        $fixtureClasses = $this->getNamespacedFixtures($fixture);

        foreach ($fixtureClasses as $fixtureClass) {
            $reflect  = new \ReflectionClass($fixtureClass);
            $instance = $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);

            if (!$instance instanceof FixtureInterface) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Class {$fixtureClass} does not implement FixtureInterface");
            }

            $loader->addFixture($instance);

            return;
        }

        throw FixtureNotFoundException::create($fixture);
    }


    /**
     * @AfterScenario
     *
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function closeDBALConnections()
    {
        /** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
        foreach ($this->getEntityManagers() as $entityManager) {
            $entityManager->clear();
        }
        /** @var Connection $connection */
        foreach ($this->getConnections() as $connection) {
            $connection->close();
        }
    }


    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Getters and Setters
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    /**
     * @param $fixturesDir
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function addFixtureNamespace($fixturesDir)
    {
        if (!isset($this->fixtureNamespaces)) {
            $this->fixtureNamespaces = [];
        }

        if (!in_array($fixturesDir, $this->fixtureNamespaces)) {
            $this->fixtureNamespaces[] = $fixturesDir;
        }

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Sets Kernel instance.
     *
     * @param KernelInterface $kernel
     */
    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }


    /**
     * @return ContainerInterface
     */
    protected function getContainer()
    {
        return $this->kernel->getContainer();
    }


    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getMetadata(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        return $entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
    }


    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getEntityManagers()
    {
        return $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManagers();
    }


    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        $em = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        return $em;
    }


    /**
     * @return Connection[]
     */
    protected function getConnections()
    {
        return $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getConnections();
    }


    /**
     * @return ORMExecutor
     */
    public function getExecutor()
    {
        return $this->executor;
    }


    /**
     * @return ReferenceRepository
     */
    public function getReferenceRepository()
    {
        return $this->executor->getReferenceRepository();
    }


    /**
     * @param string $fixtureClass
     *
     * @return FixtureInterface
     *
     * @throws \OutOfBoundsException if fixture not found
     */
    public function getFixture($fixtureClass)
    {
        try {
            $userFixture = $this->_getFixture($fixtureClass);
        } catch (\OutOfBoundsException $exception) {
            $fixtures = $this->getNamespacedFixtures($fixtureClass);

            if (empty($fixtures)) {
                throw new \OutOfBoundsException("Fixture {$fixtureClass} not found");
            }

            if (count($fixtures) > 1) {
                throw new \LogicException(
                    "Found multiple {$fixtureClass} fixtures.  Use the full namespace to correct"
                );
            }

            /** @var AbstractSingleFixture $userFixture */
            $userFixture = $this->_getFixture($fixtures[0]);
        }

        return $userFixture;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $fixtureClass
     *
     * @return FixtureInterface
     *
     * @throws \OutOfBoundsException if fixture not found
     */
    protected function _getFixture($fixtureClass)
    {
        foreach ($this->loader->getFixtures() as $fixture) {
            if (is_a($fixture, $fixtureClass)) {
                return $fixture;
            }
        }

        throw new \OutOfBoundsException("Fixture '{$fixtureClass}' not found'");
    }


    /**
     * @param $fixtureClass
     *
     * @return object
     *
     * @throw \OutOfBoundsException if fixture is not found
     */
    public function getFixtureEntity($fixtureClass)
    {
        // Fixture class could be a shorthand, without namespace, so we use getFixture to get the full class name…
        $fixture      = $this->getFixture($fixtureClass);
        $fixtureClass = get_class($fixture);

        $referenceRepository = $this->getReferenceRepository();

        if (!$referenceRepository->hasReference($fixtureClass)) {
            throw new \OutOfBoundsException("Fixture '{$fixtureClass}' not found");
        }

        return $referenceRepository->getReference($fixtureClass);
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork.php

```
# /project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php showing line 2058
# (marked on RH side of code)

<?php

namespace Doctrine\ORM;

use ...

class UnitOfWork implements PropertyChangedListener
{

    // ...

    /**
     * Executes a refresh operation on an entity.
     *
     * @param object $entity  The entity to refresh.
     * @param array  $visited The already visited entities during cascades.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws ORMInvalidArgumentException If the entity is not MANAGED.
     */
    private function doRefresh($entity, array &$visited)
    {
        $oid = spl_object_hash($entity);

        if (isset($visited[$oid])) {
            return; // Prevent infinite recursion
        }

        $visited[$oid] = $entity; // mark visited

        $class = $this->em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

        if ($this->getEntityState($entity) !== self::STATE_MANAGED) {
            throw ORMInvalidArgumentException::entityNotManaged($entity);
        }

        $this->getEntityPersister($class->name)->refresh(
            array_combine($class->getIdentifierFieldNames(), $this->entityIdentifiers[$oid]),      <===== Line 2058
            $entity
        );

        $this->cascadeRefresh($entity, $visited);
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'll not post all my context classes here, but if you need more info, please let me know.

Any help or pointers with this would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you're fetching the entity, why are you also merging and refreshing it? Show us the context please.

Comment: @JakubZalas - Because the data may have changed during the course of the test, so need to check the latest version is being considered (although not in these tests)

Comment: Are you using any kind of doctrine cache in your test environment? If so, try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your scenarios aren't "teared down" correctly.

I have to solutions to this problem:

**1) SLOW APPROACH**

Recreate DB data (so, load fixtures basically) each time you run a new scenario

**2) FASTER APPROACH**

Run every scenario in transaction and discard all changes after each scenario has finished

Your tests should be isolated and never be affected from other test that runs before or after them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however I am already clearing the d/b out before each scenario, and re-loading the fixtures.

Comment: @TobyG: what do you mean with "clearing the db"? If you detach entities or something like this, you're not clearing nothing :) or, at least, is safer to follow my approach, trust me... I'm quite experienced with this strange executions :)

Comment: I've added the code used to clear the d/b to the main question